# Facebook Instagram GraphAPI to publish stories

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have been reading through the Facebook Instagram GraphAPI documentation and have read information that seems to be contradictory.

My question is simple really, can the GraphAPI be used to post a story to Instagram.  I am trying to write an app to schedule stories to be posted to instagram.

So, does the GraphAPI allow me to do this?

I have seen apps in the App Store that allow that to be done, but I cannot find any GraphAPI documentation that explains how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing Only available for business accounts though.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however, as per the doc you sent under Limitations: "Stories are not supported."  I am trying to publish Stories

Comment: There’s also https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories

Comment: Ahh, yes.  I have worked with that also, however, that requires user intervention and I do not want that.  I want to automatically publish a story. But thank you for continuing to help.